# How to retain kwargs between the CBV calls

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have details screen where you are re-directed to a "upload" screen with the selected pk value. Also the upload screen itself can work without kwargs and in this case (absense of pk), it will pickup/create a temporary record per user and continue use it.

However, when I re-direct to the "upload" screen with a pk, the value vanishes during multiple file upload

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(UploadImages, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    if "pk" in self.kwargs:
        context.update({'taid':self.kwargs['pk']})
    elif context.get("taid") is None:
        context.update({'taid':self._get_usr_tmp_album()})

    return context
```

When uploading files, the form_valid is called per file which in turn get_context_data is called every time. When this happens, the self.kwargs returns empty (despite the ID is on the URL) and hence, the code resorts to create/read a temporary record for that user and return it.

```
def form_valid(self,form):
    context = self.get_context_data(form=form)

    if self.request.is_ajax():
        album_id = context['taid']
```

URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/images/complete-upload/61/
```

Is there a way to retrieve the same ID from the URL during the CBV lifecycle? I tried the session and it got into different issues altogether.